# Laravel: Grabbing the highest price inventory item

Tags: php, laravel

I'm extending on a `Product` query at the end, checks the `Inventory` model and sums the `quantity` field of all `Inventory` items that have their `products_id` field match `products.id`.

```
$model = Product::query()->select(\DB::raw("products.id, products.style, products.product_name, products.brand_style,
            (SELECT images.filename FROM images WHERE images.is_main = true AND products.id = images.product_id LIMIT 1) as thumb,
            COALESCE((SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM inventory WHERE products.id = inventory.product_id GROUP BY inventory.product_id), 0) as inventory_quantity,
        "));
```

I'm trying now to add a field `min_price` that now instead of summing the quantity, will look at the price of each Inventory item and track the lowest.  I come from a javascript world so I can't see how to do so.

Comment: You should really try to write this query in a way that uses Eloquent; you have the `Product` model, you should also have `Image`, `Inventory`, etc that you can query or use functions to calculate all this. Also, sidenote, are you looking for the lowest or the highest? Your title says "highest", but your question says "lowest"...

Comment: It will all become much easier and leaner if you create Eloquent relationships for images and inventory at you Product model. You will be able to get the main image, the sum of quantity and minimum price using model attributes and fluent calls.